# dynamic columns disappears after postback

Tags: asp.net, gridview, controls, postback

I have a `GridView` with some `BoundFields` and two `TemplateFields`. In these two `TemplateFields`, I dynamically create `UserControls` containing a `DropDownList` and a `TextBox`, which users can modify.

When I try to get the values of the controls after a `PostBack`, the values in `BoundFields` are still there but my dynamic controls disappears. I can create them again but it won't get the user's values... How can I get these values before they're lost?

Here's some of my code:

**In the `RowDataBound` event:**

```
Select Case type
    Case "BooleanBis"
        e.Row.Cells(2).Controls.Clear()
        Dim list1 As BooleanBisList = New BooleanBisList(avant, False)
        e.Row.Cells(2).Controls.Add(list1)

        e.Row.Cells(4).Controls.Clear()
        Dim list2 As BooleanBisList = New BooleanBisList(apres, True)
        e.Row.Cells(4).Controls.Add(list2)
    Case "Boolean"
        e.Row.Cells(2).Controls.Clear()
        Dim list3 As BooleanList = New BooleanList(avant, False)
        e.Row.Cells(2).Controls.Add(list3)

        e.Row.Cells(4).Controls.Clear()
        Dim list4 As BooleanList = New BooleanList(apres, True)
        e.Row.Cells(4).Controls.Add(list4)
End Select
```

In my button click event, I try to get the user control :

```
Case "String"
    temp.ChampValeurApres = DirectCast(Tableau1.Rows(i).Cells(selectedColumn).Controls(1), TextBox).Text
```

but i get the error that it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should create dynamic controls in [RowCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated.aspx) instead of [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) because this event gets fired on every postback whereas `RowDataBound` only will fire when the `GridView` gets databound to it's `DataSource`.

Dynamically created controls must be recreated on every postback with the same ID as before, then they retain their values in the [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) and events will fire correctly(f.e. a DropDownList's `SelectedIndexChanged` event).

So you should create them in `RowCreated` and "fill" them in `RowDataBound`(f.e. the `DropDownList` datasource/Items or a `TextBox`-Text).

Comment: Thank you very much ! i still have a problem, i have column with readonly controls. and the value of these controls is not retrieved after the postback. any idea ?

Comment: @user874854: `readonly` controls does not maintain changes on clientside in the ViewState(only changes on serverside). Make them `readonly` via [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes.aspx)-collection, for example: `TextBox1.Attributes.Add("readonly","readonly");`. On this way you fool ASP.NET. Look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Readonly.aspx) for further infos.

Answer (score 0):

I had been using:

```
EnableViewState="false"
```

in the `GridView` attributes. Removing it solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I just did

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!(Page.IsPostBack))
    {
        // Put the selected items which u want to keep on postback
    }
    else
    {
        //regenerate auto created controls
    }
}
```

and it worked as well